# Overriding CORS on Kubernetes leads to a connection error

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying a test where I enable CORS for all domains (to be restricted after I get the use-case working correctly).

As far as I can tell, I should be adding `--cors-allowed-origins=["http://*"]` to my `kube-apiserver.manifest`

When I try to do that however:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - /usr/local/bin/kube-apiserver --address=127.0.0.1 --admission-control=Initializers,NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,PersistentVolumeLabel,DefaultStorageClass,DefaultTolerationSeconds,NodeRestriction,Priority,ResourceQuota
      --allow-privileged=true --anonymous-auth=false --apiserver-count=1 --authorization-mode=AlwaysAllow
      --basic-auth-file=/srv/kubernetes/basic_auth.csv --client-ca-file=/srv/kubernetes/ca.crt
      --cloud-provider=aws --etcd-servers-overrides=/events#http://127.0.0.1:4002
      --etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001 --insecure-port=8080 --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,Hostname,ExternalIP
      --proxy-client-cert-file=/srv/kubernetes/apiserver-aggregator.cert --proxy-client-key-file=/srv/kubernetes/apiserver-aggregator.key
      --requestheader-allowed-names=aggregator --requestheader-client-ca-file=/srv/kubernetes/apiserver-aggregator-ca.cert
      --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra- --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
      --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User --secure-port=443 --service-cluster-ip-range=100.64.0.0/13
      --storage-backend=etcd2 --tls-cert-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.cert --tls-private-key-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.key
      --token-auth-file=/srv/kubernetes/known_tokens.csv --v=2 2>&1 | /bin/tee -a
      --cors-allowed-origins=["https://*"]
```

I get the following error when trying to use kubectl get pods:

```
The connection to the server 127.0.0.1 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

What exactly am I doing wrong for the setup? How do I add CORS domains to Kubernetes?

EDIT: I am now trying this:

```
- kube-apiserver
  --cors-allowed-origins=["https://*"]
```

My pods no longer crash, however I still have CORS issues in my application.

I am getting errors like this:

```
[Error] Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/auth/realms/name/protocol/openid-connect/token due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (token, line 0)
[Error] Preflight response is not successful
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/api/v1/users/me/profile? due to access control checks.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to access your api-server with the http protocol, try:

```
--cors-allowed-origins=["http://*"]
```

Comment: I’m getting CORS issues with http and https

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation:

> --cors-allowed-origins: List of allowed origins for CORS, comma separated. An allowed origin can be a regular expression to support subdomain matching. If this list is empty CORS will not be enabled.

I have tested this settings (and also http//*) against API and it works:

```
--cors-allowed-origins=example.com,example2.com

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
```

Those errors looks like problem with settings on your serverside app.

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: specifies the authorized domains to make cross-domain request (you should include the domains of your REST clients or “*” if you want the resource public and available to everyone – the latter is not an option if credentials are allowed during CORS requests)

hope this help.

Comment: So you're saying that you feel my kubernetes setup is correct?

Comment: I am not sure because there are missing information about your app deployment, but it seems you should setup your serverside app to get desired effect.

Comment: I guess I am just not understanding how Kubernetes does access control. I thought this was where access control for the API was configured.

Comment: Now I'm confused. `CORS, or Cross-origin resource sharing consists of a few HTTP response headers intended to let a web browser know if it’s ok to POST data to a specific endpoint`. In my example the request was made against  Kubernetes API. In your case probably you are using different endpoint. F.E. for nginx confgi you should probably use `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*'` [example](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)

Comment: I am using my application endpoint - would that be configured elsewhere than in the kubernetes API config files? I'm sorry I'm so confused, I just really don't know how Kubernetes works when it comes to this. I'm brand new to it and trying to figure it out

Comment: As described above: [here](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html) is an example how to configure your server side like nginx, [here](https://imti.co/kubernetes-ingress-nginx-cors/) is an example how to configure nginx ingress, and [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/oci/apps/wordpress/configuration/enable-cors-wordpress/) you can find f.e. settings for bitnami WP. So, you should start looking for information related to your application endpoint architecture.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just think this is all too different from the setup I inherited. I'm going to need to do a lot more research.